# Adding a list of social media links

Tags: facebook

I want to add a list of my social media pages. What ways are there to do this? Are there widgets designed for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. You can do as Chris Carson suggested and manually add them as a text menu. You can also make a text widget and use icons with links to the various services.

If you're looking for something a little more robust, there's also a couple plugins and related services, such as AddThis, that do the icon and linking work for you and also let you track hit counts and such if you sign up for their free services.

Answer (score 1):

Use a menu, which is designed for listing links: Admin->Appearance->Menus.  Then add that menu to your sidebar with the menu widget: Admin->Appearance->Widgets.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use wordpress [sharethis](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/share-this/) plugin. Because it has more features. Check [these screenshots](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/share-this/screenshots/)